# Multiple lines in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any method to depict multiple curves in the same plot using python, let's say for example 20 curves in the same plot. I have found a solution by adding colors (Red, Green, Blue, etc.). Thank you for your time.

```
plt.plot(x,'g')
plt.plot(y,'r')
plt.plot(z,'b')







what about number 20?
```

Comment: I suggest spending some time with the matplotlib [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) and [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) to address problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `set_color_cycle` which sets the color cycle for any future plot commands on this Axes.

[DOCS](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.5/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
colormap = plt.cm.gist_ncar
total_num_plots = 20
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color', plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, total_num_plots))))
x = np.arange(10)
labels=[]
for i in range(1,total_num_plots+1):
    plt.plot(x, i*x)
    labels.append(f'{i}*X')
plt.legend(labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample Graph]

Comment: SO has the duplicate flag for a reason.

Comment: @Jack21 If your query is resolved, please mark this as an answer!